# Firebase Facebook Auth Identifier is -

Tags: android, firebase, kotlin, facebook-graph-api, firebase-authentication

I just created Facebook login on my Android app by using Firebase Auth but to my surprise the identifier appears to be -

[image: Example of Facebook identifier in Firebase]

How can I retrieve the user's email and put it as the Firebase's identifier?

Thanks

Comment: same problem! did u find a solution or what causes this?

Comment: Been searching for ages and still couldnt find the solution. Ended up with not using Facebook auth @HassanElkhalifte

Comment: i have found the answer, look at my answer.

Answer (score 0):

this is not actually a problem by firebase or facebook.
if the identifier was just a "-", it means that the facebook account used for registration does not have an email (facebook account created with a phone number).